# Record and stream desktop to Youtube by ffmpeg with HD resolution

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, h.264

I want to record and stream desktop to Youtube live by FFmpeg. But the output resolution is very low, maximum 360.
What options I need to change?

```
ffmpeg  -framerate 30 -f x11grab -i :1 -f pulse -i default -c:v libx264 -s 1920x1080 -r 60 -b:v 5000k  -crf 10 -vf format=yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/stream_key
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

[Default size for x11grab](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#Options-20) is the full desktop or window (640x480 for old ffmpeg versions). Your ffmpeg is old, so it is capturing at 640x480. You are then upscaling 640x480 to 1920x1080 which is bad and looks ugly.

## Solution 1: Upgrade ffmpeg

Fix by using a modern ffmpeg version and it will grab the full desktop or window size by default. See [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links or the [FFmpeg compile and install guides](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide).

## Solution 2: Use `-video_size` input option

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -video_size 1920x1080 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f pulse -i default -c:v libx264 -b:v 5000k -maxrate 5000k -bufsize 10000k -g 60 -vf format=yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/stream_key
```

- See the [FFmpeg x11grab documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#x11grab) for more info and options.
- For streaming it is [recommended](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites) to add `-g`, `-bufsize`, and `-maxrate` to enable VBV.